# Need to re-install Windows 7 after motherboard change?

Tags: windows-7, installation, motherboard

My motherboard died, and I had to change it.

Does this mean that i need to reinstall Windows-7 ?
Or can I make it load somehow, and then just install the new board's drivers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work without reinstalling. I guess you have new motherboard which is different then the one you've had before. Unless there are some big changes there should be no problems for Windows 7 to find changes and update accordingly.

Edit:

In worst case scenario you can fix Windows by starting it up from DVD and choosing repair option (in case anything in `bootmgr` or `boot.ini` got problems.

But I would suggest posting exact problems you have (full error message) and checking bios settings.

Comment: Ok, but it says something about boot.ini not being right and doesn't load

Comment: What's the exact message? You sure drives are connected properly and proper boot order is chosen in bios?

Comment: Says Boot.ini is not correct. Then tries to load from c:\windows ... Says \system32\hal.dll is corrupt or missing

Comment: Also have anything else changed other then motherboard? Do you have model for old mobo and new mobo at hand?

Comment: Try the other IDE/SATA port on the motherboard. I think the boot.ini may have the information included at which port to look for the drive. Read this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102873

Comment: Changing SATA port worked :) tahnks

Comment: @Yochai Timmer: did Windows 7 actually refer to `boot.ini`? That's odd.

Answer (score 1):

You can boot your computer and then install the new drivers required by your new motherboard.

And you don't need to reinstall Windows 7.

You only need to install any new drivers required by your new motherboard.

*Also See*
[Error message: "Windows could not start because of a computer disk hardware configuration problem" (Windows XP)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314477)

[How To Fix Hal.dll Errors in Windows 7 and Windows Vista](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/hal-dll-missing-windows-7-vista.htm)

Comment: It doesn't load. Says Boot.ini is not correct. Then tries to load from c:\windows ... Says \system32\hal.dll is corrupt or missing

Answer (score -1):

The other cases were already handled by the other answers. But let me add one consideration:

Should you have used a [TPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module)-based encryption - such as [BitLocker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker_Drive_Encryption) - things would be a bit more complicated. It is possible, though, to create recovery media for this *in advance*. If you haven't done this, you're out of luck and would also have lost the data on any BitLocker-secured drives.

Comment: Good point, but you just need the recovery code, which Windows forces you to save somewhere else or print before it lets you encrypt.